# How to specify filtered Backbone collection for Marionette view

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, backbone-views

I have a Marionette composite view that displays a collection, which I set in my Application start handler:

```
App.on('start', function() {
  Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});

  // I load up this.appsCollection in my before:start handler
  var tblView = new this.appsTableView({
    collection: this.appsCollection
  });

  this.regions.main.show(tblView);
});
```

This works as expected, displaying my entire collection.  In my models, I have a state field, and I want to display only models with state 0.  I tried:

```
collection: this.appsCollection.where({state: 0})
```

but that doesn't work.  I actually want to display states in 0 and 1, but I'm trying to just display state in 0 for right now.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to override the filter method in my Marionette CompositeView:

http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.3/marionette.collectionview.html#collectionviews-filter

Answer (score 3):

The problem probably resides in that `.where()` doesn't return a collection, but an array.  http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-where  This was supposedly to maintain compatibility with underscore.

If you change the line to:

```
collection: new Backbone.Collection( this.appsCollection.where( { state: 0 } ))
```

Does that help?

Comment: A collection is a wrapped array with lots of extra methods and data.